# Multi-flex grow configuration

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

So, I have this HTML block in this [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/pagifugube/edit?html,css,js,output) that has a `ul` in the structure:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

Inside each `li` I have 5 divs:

```
<div class="image"></div>  <!-- fixed height-->
<div class="desc"></div>   <!-- variant height-->
<div class="icons"></div>  <!-- fixed height-->
<div class="promo"></div>  <!-- fixed height-->
<div class="button"></div> <!-- expandable to fix height-->
```

I've used `flex` to make the `ul` responsive and for the `li`'s to get nice and aligned.

The objective of this structure is for the items in the same row to have the same height. Because `.desc` has a variable height, I've set `flex-grow: 1`. However now comes my problem. I need `.button` to be expandable but only when it is clicked. But if I set `flex-grow: 1` to it as well, they will share the height and I don't want that.

So what I'm having trouble to achieve is to have the `.desc` height variable and matching the highest in the row, and `.button` to extend in all the elements in the row. I have a solution with `javascript`, but when the items start to increase it is very slow (as the height of the elements is also controlled by `javascript`). If this question already has an answer I apologize, but I just weren't having a lot of luck with my search.

Comment: It's not entirely clear on what it is you are trying to do but flexbox cannot equalise heights of elements that do not share a parent. JS would be your only recourse.

Comment: Here's the most I was able to achieve in terms of ["flex-galery"](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/no73st0h/) As you can see they're only bound on one direction. For binding (and flexing) on two directions, you'll need [CSS Grid](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). Until than, you're better off using [d3](https://d3js.org/), for that matter. Note your exact desired behavior is currently unclear. Adding a [mcve] would probably help us understand your request.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have a way with words. But basically I want to use something like flex-grow to link the height of all the .desc in that row, and the same for .button. Button has a fixed expansion height, but .desc can vary from item to item. And also have the same height for all the .item in that row.

I've managed with 1 flex-grow, but with more than one I can't seem to get it to work.